# Ruby - comparing adjacent entries in one column of a csv file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm new to Ruby, so apologies if this is dead easy :-)

I have a .csv file with 5 columns. The first column has a record identifier (in this case a driver number) and the other 4 columns in each row have data relating to that record. For each record there are around 50 rows of data (just under 2,000 rows in total). The .csv file has a header row.

I need to read the .csv file and identify the last entry for each user, so I can move on to the next user. I've tried to get it to compare the first column and the entry in the next row.

I have this so far, it returns incorrect row numbers and they're anywhere between 1 and 5 rows out...?!?!

```
require 'csv-mapper'

  Given(/^I compare the driver numbers from rows "(.*?)" to "(.*?)"$/) do |firstrow, lastrow|
    data = CsvMapper.import('C:/auto_test_data/Courts code example csv.csv', headers: true) do
      [dln]
    end

    row = firstrow.to_i
    while row <= lastrow.to_i
      @licnum1 = data.at(row).dln
      @licnum2 = data.at(row+1).dln

      if
        @licnum2 == @licnum1
          $newrecord = "same"
      else
        $newrecord = @licnum2
      end

      if   
        $newrecord != "same"
        puts "Last row for #{@licnum1} is #{row}\n"
      end

      row = row + 1
    end
  end
```

This is the layout for the .csv file:

```
recordidentifier1   dataitem1   dataitem2 code descriptionforcomparison
recordidentifier1   dataitem1   dataitem2 code descriptionforcomparison
recordidentifier2   dataitem1   dataitem2 code descriptionforcomparison
recordidentifier2   dataitem1   dataitem2 code descriptionforcomparison
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
current_identifier = nil

(firstrow.to_i..lastrow.to_i).each do |row|

  if current_identifer != data.at(row).dln # current row is new identifier
    if current_identifier # this is not the first row
       puts "Last row for #{current_identifier} is #{row-1}\n"
    end
    current_identifier = data.at(row).dln # remember current row
  end

  # we need to track the last row as the last for the current identifier
  puts "Last row for #{current_identifier} is #{lastrow.to_i}\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, gents :-) Cheers for tidying up the question, @peter.

Comment: I got there in the end.